# Shopify Product Description Copying

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am using Shopify to manage my online store and have noticed that when I update the description for one product, the same description is automatically applied to all other products within my website. What is the solution to this issue to create unique product pages for each item in my store?

I tried using the actual product description under the products tab rather than changing the product page, but it does not allow me to use the customization that I need to display my products.

[Here is an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Qr1.png)